# How can I make a Typescript interface with variable property names?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I'm trying to write a type alias or interface whose property names are dependent upon user input. Essentially I want to say, 'accept an object that has the following properties whose keys will be specified by the user *here*.'

```
const userDefinedPropNames = { xVal: 'somestring', yVal: 'anotherstring', group: 'athirdstring' }

interface Data {
  somestring: number,
  anotherstring: number,
  athirdstring: string,

}
```

I've attempted to solve this in a couple of ways: using mapped types,

```
interface PreData {
  xVal: number,
  yVal: number,
  group: string
}

const val = 'asdf' 

type Data = renameProps<PreData> //Record<`${val}`, number> 

type renameProps<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type as `${val}`]: Type[Property]
}
```

and using Record

```
type Data = Record<`${val}`, number>
```

In both cases, I get the same error:

> 'val' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof val'?ts(2749)
> Exported type alias 'renameProps' has or is using private name 'val'.

Curiously, the errors go away if I replace the template literal expression with a string or basic template literal:

```
type Data = Record<`myval`, number>
```

This gets rid of the error, but does not achieve what I'm trying to.

I've also tried just using a variable instead of template literal, but that causes the same error:

```
type Data = Record<val, number>
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the desired result type for `type Data` in example above

Comment: If you want to extract literal type from const, you should use `typeof`. E.g `Record<typeof val, number>`

Comment: The desired result type is 

interface Data {
  somestring: number,
  anotherstring: number,
  athirdstring: string,
}, 
where 'somestring', 'anotherstring', 'athirdstring' represent strings defined by the user.

Comment: would typeof val evaluate to string or to 'asdf'?

Comment: Something like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJwCKIGYEsyICYAKyIADgHICGAtohDALwwDeMAHgGoUA2AXDAOQQQNaMhwBzfgBoYAT068BFMCCgALFKInSY44nBJ9+FdVmR4tYSTAC+MCnVCQoAWABQ7nFBQYKwRDBEiKgmFMzuMGwKfGBwVABGKFIRctEwsQlJKXogBnyW4u427u5QsiQBAEqIYNSIRKQQADwA0oiyALIUJDCIrN5gFjDVoOZNANbtIBgwCnCIXSQyBQB8MnML3SsM4W6RANotMDgwk7LTs9zzi-Z0AAYAJExtnd2HALo2d+98G4sfRRKbjKFRgISgYUY1VqNAaJGaIMQFwQKHQ2FwhGI5DqEBkQXBFBWQA ?

Comment: @Faero to be clear, by "user input" do you mean a user of your software, where they enter these strings into text fields (unknowable at compile time)? Or you do mean a consumer of this library where some developer may supply this code with their own strings (knowable at compile time, but in the context of a larger codebase)?

Comment: @AlexWayne The user i'm talking about is the developer who uses my library. I'm making a library of react chart components using D3. My hope was to allow developers to instantiate a chart, passing in the data along with various attributes. One of those attributes would specify which keys of the input data to be used as the x value, y value, and groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
type Data<T extends Record<string, any>> = T;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, could you explain what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: This is a type that takes one type argument (a Record), where the keys are strings and the values are any type.

This means if a user has an object:

```ts
const obj: MyObj = {
   something: 'somestring',
   else: false
}

type NewType = Data<MyObj> // will be the key/value pairs of obj
```